# Want to Retrieve Email field from database and show in Selenium Xpath

Tags: java, mysql, xpath, jdbc, selenium-webdriver

Want to Retrieve Email field from database and show in xpath 
Here is my code kindly check it i'm providing my Selenium Xpath class and my db class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully..."); //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "SELECT client_id, first_name, last_name, email FROM person";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         int id  = rs.getInt("client_id");
         String email = rs.getString("email");
         String first = rs.getString("first_name");
         String last = rs.getString("last_name");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + email);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
    public class Login extends DB {

    public void Loginfill(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-loginButton")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_username")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_password")).sendKeys("learnship123$");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div[2]/div[2]/div/form[1]/button")).click();    
    }
}
```

Please help me to confgiure out what i have to do

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you have any error? What do you want to do with xpath and email, I dont understand

Comment: i want email that is in database want to show in mylanding page login form that xpath is driver.findElement(By.id("login_username")).sendKeys(""); that i smentioned on above code in Login fill method() kindly help me to how to pass my varibale of email id of data base varibale that is String sql = "SELECT client_id, first_name, last_name, email FROM person";
     System.out.print(", Age: " + email);

Comment: kindly help me to bulid logic

Comment: Kindly open the snapshot link to view https://s16.postimg.org/pbf4prejp/image.png     https://s18.postimg.org/sm8hze62x/landingpage.png

Comment: Ok, I understand. So: 1. do you have a problem with locating username field in login form, or 2. do you have a problem with getting an email from database?

Comment: yes offcorse kindly help me resolve my problem

Comment: @Shaishav Jogani please help em to configure out this problem

Comment: I try, but you didnt answer my questions. What is the problem? Is the problem get email from database, or find and fill username field?

Comment: yes i already told you my problem is get email from database, or find and fill username field

Comment: What is the output from `System.out.print(", Age: " + email);`? is it printing correct email?

Comment: Yes its printing correct email

Comment: So why have you written "my problem is get email from database"?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think something like this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

String email = getEmail();
Login.LoginFill(email);
}

static String getEmail() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully..."); //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT email FROM person";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    //STEP 5: Extract data from result set

    String email = rs.getString("email");

    //Display values
    System.out.print(", email: " + email);

    return email;
}
class Login {

    public static void Loginfill(String email){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-loginButton")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_username")).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_password")).sendKeys("learnship123$");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div[2]/div[2]/div/form[1]/button")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)

Comment: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:618)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:1054)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:1071)

Comment: at DB.getEmail(DB.java:47)
 at DB.main(DB.java:29)

Comment: These errors are i'm facing now after putting your code

Comment: i think this is not full stack trace

Comment: what did you mean full stack trace ??

Comment: help me please its not resolving